# "for" VS "because"

Tags: conjunctions

I have a question regarding the nature of the conjunctions "for" and "because".

The former is known to form part of the famous acronym FANBOYS, that encompasses the most common **coordinate** conjunctions, whilst the latter represents one of the **subordinate** ones. Still, they appear to share the same semantic properties and express the same relation.

*The dude is not coming because he is mad at you* - the second clause gives the reason for the dude's not coming => it is dependent;

*The duke is not coming, for he is no more* - same relationship, only slightly more poetically put => it is dependent.

I'm sure these conjunctions have been "separated" for a good reason, so could you please explain why we consider "for" to be a coordinate conjunction?

Comment: Welcome to ELU.SE. Thank you, Vsevolod IV, this is a nice first question. Even though you got the gist of ELU already, you can take the [tour] or have a look at the [help] to find out more about good questions.

Answer (score 0):

The point is that the coordinating conjunction has to come in the middle between the two sentences. Consider this [blog entry from grammar girl](http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/can-i-start-a-sentence-with-a-conjunction?page=2).

The first sentence you can rephrase to:

> Because he is mad at you, the dude is not coming.

On the other hand this makes no sense:

> For he is no more. The duke is not coming.

Comment: That is exactly what I've been looking for! I knew there was something wrong with that FANBOY thing!

Comment: Thank you both for the link and for suggesting related posts, Helmar. You have been of great help:)